# UIBarButtonItem Initializer with Image and Title does not show Title

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I am using `init(title:image:primaryAction:menu:)` of a UIBarButtonItem [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/3600776-init) on a Toolbar with the hope of showing a button with both image and title. Does anyone know why the title does not show?
I am **not** looking for a custom implementation that can add a UIBarButtonItem with title and image. I have seen plenty on Stackoverflow. I just want to use this initializer if it works.

I have a UITableViewController subclass and I have added this code to the viewDidLoad

```
navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "New Item", image: UIImage(systemName: "plus.circle.fill"), primaryAction: nil, menu: nil)
toolbarItems = [barButtonItem]
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that since `public convenience init(title: String? = nil, image: UIImage? = nil, primaryAction: UIAction? = nil, menu: UIMenu? = nil)` is a `convenience` init, and the fact that there is no init that initialize with both title and image, then using both at the same time is not supported. It's merely a convenience on using primaryAction and menu then having title and image.

Comment: You are completely right. I think that we can either initialize the title or image. Also, if you try to use the same with title, image and primaryAction, and actually use a UIAction() { // handler }, it replaces the title in the initializer for the title in the UIAction initializer you should either use set the title in the UIAction initializer or add the title before setting the action

Answer (score 1):

Try to assign a custom button to your navBar button, declare your button under your controller class:

```
let myButton = UIButton(type: .system)
```

now in viewDidLoad set your custom button with title and assign it to navigation bar:

```
myButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up"), for: .normal)
myButton.setTitle(" your text", for: .normal)
myButton.sizeToFit()
myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourFunctionAction), for: .touchUpInside)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: myButton)
```

Comment: Thanks! But as I had mentioned in my question I have seen many of these answers on Stackoverflow before with custom implementation as yours. There is nothing wrong with that but that's not my question. I wanna see why the specific Apple provided initializer does not work.